# Simultaneous TCP Open

Tags: c++, networking

I am implementing "simultaneous TCP Open".That means both peer will try to connect each other at the same time. I confused whether listen is rquired or not in this case.

or tell me the sequence of socket need to be called for each client.

I am implementing this for TCp hole Punching.

thanks,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [Wikipedia's article on TCP hole punching](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TCP_hole_punching):

> Because both parties are connection TO
>   each other (e.g. 2 x CONNECT(), no
>   LISTEN(), ACCEPT(), etc.) to generate
>   OUTBOUND traffic there is however a
>   problem with:
>
> TCP Sequence numbers
>
> Acknowledgment numbers
>
> The required state is just like after
>   the three-way-handshake: Each host
>   must have an acknowledge number ==
>   other sequence number + 1. This is
>   achieved through Sequence and
>   Acknowledgement Number coordination.

listen() is not needed.  The sequence depends on what is available.

Comment: You mean to say both accept and listen is not required in  this case.

Comment: can you advice me how to tackle TCP Sequence numbers

Acknowledgment numbers problem